# How to build the 3d cartesian coordinate system like this and add this graph

Tags: pgfplots, 3d, tikz-3dplot, tikz-3d, pst-solides3d

[image]

When I used the pgfplots or tikz3d I have a problem that the x,y,z axis doesn't like this.
They always incline from it should be like the below image. How to set the x,y,z axis that [x-axis is towards to the observer](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/83/Coord_planes_color.svg/1024px-Coord_planes_color.svg.png) click to this link for information.